# Encountering Issue when Creating Spring Boot Module with JDK 21 in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4 on Windows 11

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm facing a puzzling problem when trying to create a new Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4. The error message I encounter is as follows:

"The environment variable Javahome (with the value of D:\develop\jdk-21) does not point to a valid JVM installation."

- This issue only occurs when attempting to create a new Spring Boot module in IntelliJ IDEA; opening existing projects works without issues.
- I've validated that my JDK 21 installation is functioning properly, and JAVA_HOME points to the correct directory.

[check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7O8t.png)

[check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTWAA.png)

[check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErSN1.png)

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvqUv.png)

- Operating System: Windows 11
- IntelliJ IDEA Version: 2023.2.4
- Java Version: JDK 21

I'm working hard to resolve this problem, and I greatly appreciate any assistance, guidance, or advice. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show log in..."). Are there any related errors/warnings?

Comment: There are some warnings related to maven, but I don't know if they are causing this problem